# Can't connect a Unity C# script to a remote MySQL Database hosted in Railway

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, connection

I have a C# script for a Unity game whose function is to connect to a database in MySQL to retrieve and store information. The game will work almost completely on local, except for the database, that will be on remote to store info about player accounts.

I connected successfully to a local database in MySQL using a MySQLConnection object and I have been able to store and retrieve data to test the code that interacts with the database. Those are the following credentials that worked in local (the darkened fields are the passwords for the database):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbvIL.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy2v7.jpg)

The credentials that worked making the connection in local are connecting to localhost and specifying the database, user and the password.
In Railway I have available this info to connect:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N46i.jpg)

With the MYSQLHOST and the port I have been able to connect with MySQL Workbench from my machine and do changes to the database (So I know that the database is accessible remotely). But I can’t connect from the C# script, neither with the MYSQL_URL neither with MYSQLHOST, I tried also specifying “;dns-srv=true” when using MYSQLHOST, but nothing is working.

In all cases it gives me the error that is unable to locate the host: "ERROR: DatabaseMediator:Awake:MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to locate any hosts for containers-us-west-110.railway.app" "ERROR: DatabaseMediator:Awake:MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to locate any hosts for mysql://root:password@containers-us-west-110.railway.app:6058/railway"

I feel like I am missing something simple or basic, maybe I have to specify the dns and the port some way in the String entered to the constructor of the connection. I only need to know how to do the connection to get all my code of the database working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Congratulations for posting your public database password to the world.

Comment: Posting it as pics doesnt save you - iphones will highlight text and copy it. Second. Your code (dont post as pics) surely you are mixing things up. Server should be just hostname and maybe port. Db doesnt go on the end and then again as database. Same as username and password dont need to be in there twice.

Comment: Tip: Unity apps are not secure. They can be decompiled and anyone can find your database ip, user and password. That means they can edit whatever they want. Connecting or issuing queries via string concats is just asking for trouble as it is the most unsecure and exploitable thing there can ever be on a server. SQL Injections are the least of your trouble considering you just hand them an admin account password. And yes, that goes double for plugin modules such as Photon where you expose your app key. There is a reason why earlier Unity versions encrypted the Unity Services keys in the build.

Comment: Also, creating tables from inside the game is just bad design. Why would a server DB not have tables if it expects clients to add info to it? Putting aside your problem about connecting to the DB, you need to read-up and apply some best practices regarding security on your apps. I'll reiterate the second tip from earlier: using insert, update and delete with concat-ed strings as values (using the `+` operator) is unsecure and easily exploitable. And I am not talking about Unity or this game now. Don't ever design DB queries like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the `Server` in your connection string in an incorrect format. It should be just the name of the server, not `mysql://...`

Use the `MYSQLHOST` and `MYSQLPORT` values to construct the connection string. It should look like:

```
Server=MYSQLHOST; Port=MYSQLPORT; UserID=MYSQLUSER; Password=MYSQLPASSWORD; Database=MYSQLDATABASE
```

Replace the uppercase values in that string with the values from your screenshot / database configuration.